# How can I apply Group Policy object (GPO)user settings in GPO only if connecting to specific users?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I'm using Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition. How can I apply Group Policy object (GPO) user settings in GPO only if connecting to specific users?

Or to put it in another way: I want to apply a GPO to a specific user.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you'd like to accomplish.

Comment: You're not making sense. Do you mean that you want to apply a GPO to a specific user or group of users? If so, then use Security Filtering to filter on the specific user or group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Security Filtering section of the GPO (on the Scope tab) remove Authenticated Users and add the user or group in question. This will make the GPO apply to only that user or group.

Take note that the GPO has to be in the Scope of Management (SOM) of the user, meaning it has to be linked to the OU or container (domain or site) where the user object exists.

Comment: Note that it is generally considered poor practice to filter based on user accounts.  Best practice is to create a group specifically for the policy, and then add users, groups, or computers to that group.

Comment: @Bacon: True enough. I wanted to convey in my answer that it could be done based on user or group. Thanks for the assist.